Smoothing normal on GPU (using geometry shader) without knowledge to adjacent faces
Smoothing normal on GPU might be a common question because you really can generate flat normal by triangle primitives , but you don't have adjacent faces so it is not possible to smooth normal . I went into this topic without deep thinking . Now I encountered a problem .
Basically , what I thought was :
You don't have to know adjacent faces . The only thing you need to do is adding known normal which was generated by the only known triangle to the vertex that you want to generate smooth normal for . It's nice that when you're processing primitives , you can also access its vertices . If you go through all faces , for the vertices that were shared between primitives , you will access the same ID , and then you will add each faces' flattened normal to them . Finally , you got all vertices summing up with all their related faces' normal , then just normalize them .
It sounds quite nice because you don't have to require adjacent faces . You just add known information, and generate smoothed normal using mathematical tool (normalize).
//vertex
#version 450 core


struct VertexData {
    float position[3];
};

layout(binding = 0, std430) readonly buffer ssbo {
    VertexData data[];
};
layout(binding = 1, std430) readonly buffer ssbo_normal {
    VertexData auxi[];
};

vec3 getPosition(int index) {
    return vec3(
        data[index].position[0], 
        data[index].position[1], 
        data[index].position[2]
    );
}

vec3 getNormal(int index) {
    return vec3(
        auxi[index].position[0], 
        auxi[index].position[1], 
        auxi[index].position[2]
    );
}

out vec3 Normal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(getPosition(gl_VertexID), gl_VertexID);
    Normal = normalize(getNormal(gl_VertexID));
}

...
//geometry
#version 450 core
layout(triangles) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

struct VertexData {
    float position[3];
};

layout(binding = 1, std430) buffer ssbo_normal {
    VertexData auxi[];
};


void setNormal(int index, vec3 pos) {
    VertexData postruct = VertexData(float[3](pos.x,pos.y,pos.z));
    auxi[index] = postruct;
}

vec3 getNormal(int index) {
    return vec3(
        auxi[index].position[0], 
        auxi[index].position[1], 
        auxi[index].position[2]
    );
}

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 scale;
uniform mat4 move;

void main(){

    //for ssbo
    vec3 flatnormal = normalize(cross(gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz-gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz, gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz-gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz));

    float movedistance = 0.1;
    
    vec4 pos0 = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    vec4 pos1 = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    vec4 pos2 = gl_in[2].gl_Position;

    setNormal(int(pos0.w), getNormal(int(pos0.w))+flatnormal);
    setNormal(int(pos1.w), getNormal(int(pos1.w))+flatnormal);
    setNormal(int(pos2.w), getNormal(int(pos2.w))+flatnormal);

    //for rendering
    gl_Position = view * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz,1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = view * vec4(gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz,1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = view * vec4(gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz,1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = view * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz,1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}

But there's a problem . What I was going to do is performing addition without knowing operand . Addition requires two operands , one is the flattened normal , but the other is the 'original' or 'already-existed' normal . The latter one was initially zero . But it is impossible to do so in parallel GPU pipeline to let some processes know something only after some other processes are done . Otherwise why is it parallel ? The result I got was normal pointing only to one direction , not to a combination of all face normals . That was because I always read original normal as initial (0,0,0) value , and overwrite each upon each upon each ... So finally I failed.
Whole project

I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. You don't seem to be using an index buffer, so there are no shared vertices between faces. No shared vertices -> no index will show up more than once in the geometry shader, so no smoothing will ever happen.

I'm using index buffer. Drawelement is called in total times equal to triangle_counts * 3. If you have looked into my source codes , it is specified at line 500 of gridtrace.java . And it is used beginning from line 179 in the same file . Binding vertex array binds element buffer as well . And I do really use glDrawElements . If I change it to drawarray , with a large-enough number ( it seems extra draw invocations are discarded automatically) , the resulting wireframe is connected bad

@BDL  When using indexed drawing such as glDrawElements, gl_VertexID will be equal to the current index from the element array buffer. link

I see. It's kind of strange to use an index buffer, but access the positions through an SSBO (that's what got me tricked into believing you don't use an index buffer). Nevertheless, the geometry shader approach will not work out unless you get some synchronization set up. There are ways to achieve this by using an additional SSBO with an integer per vertex and implementing a spin-lock with atomic operations. And you will need an additional shader pass to normalize the normals after they have been summed up. I'm not sure though if this will be faster than a CPU implementation.

Because I want to assembly primitives correctly . SSBO contains only unique vertices .

What you usually would do for indexed inputs is to use something like in vec3 pos; and let OpenGL handle the indexing. The reason is that GPUs usually have a vertex cache which takes advantage of the indexing and provides better performance than random SSBO accesses. But this is not your current problem and switching to regular attributes wouldn't help with the normal calculation synchronization problem.
